# Unable to Access Struct Members within Template

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I decided to make my HashTable class a template so I could practice making templates, but I've run into a problem. Within my `HashTable<T>` template, I have a data member array, called `items` of `Bucket`s, which is a struct within the `HashTable<T>` class. After initializing `items`, I am unable to access the members of `Bucket` elsewhere in the template's code.

I have tried putting `typename` and `template<class T>` before the struct and variable definitions, but was unable to make it work.

Here is a snippet of code that gives me the error `'keyValue': undeclared identifier`

```
#ifndef HASH_TABLE_
#define HASH_TABLE_

using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class HashTable
{

public:

HashTable(int numItems) {
    if (numItems <= 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid HashTable size");
    }
    currItems = 0;

    //B must be the next prime after 2 * numItems
    B = 1000;

    items = Bucket[B]; //allocate array of Buckets

    items[0].keyVal; //ERROR: undeclared identifier
}

bool insert(T* newItem, int key) {
    bool retVal = false;

    if (currItems < B && newItem != NULL) { //cannot insert to full HashTable
        int index = 0;

        items[index].dataPtr = newItem; //ERROR:undeclared
        items[index].keyVal = key;      //ERROR:undeclared

        retVal = true;
        currItems++;
    }

    return retVal;
}

private:

struct Bucket {
    T* dataPtr = NULL;
    int keyVal = -1;
};

Bucket * items; //array of buckets
int B; //size of itemArray
int currItems; //track number of items in HashTable

};

#endif
```

Why does `items[x]` not access a Bucket, such that `items[x].keyVal` or `items[x].dataPtr` cannot be used? I've tried different types of initializations, such as `items = new Bucket[B]`, but that hasn't worked either, so I am assuming my errors lie in the template side of things.

I appreciate any guidance!

Comment: This piece of code does not compile due to missing nextPrime and getOpenBucket implementation, also - you do not allocate items properly (either use operator new[] or even better, change raw pointer into smart one). There are no template issues in here

Comment: I've removed nextPrime and getOpenBucket. By using new[], do you mean use `items = new Bucket[B]` instead of what I currently have? Because that has given me the same error in the past. I can't use smart pointers because I have to compile on a c++ '98 Linux machine :(

Comment: Yes, you need to allocate memory if you want to create table dynamically. Machine, that you're using doesn't matter - if you have new compiler available, then you can use new standard - and you're using c++11 feature in this code anyway ("int keyVal = -1;"). After these changes (and putting Bucket in the beginning of class) I am compiling your code without an issue.

Comment: BTW, statement that you marked as "ERROR: undeclared identifier" simply has no effect - you should remove it (but it's not an error, merely generates a warning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `Bucket` before you use it.

```
template<class T>
class HashTable
{
    struct Bucket {
        T* dataPtr = NULL;
        int keyVal = -1;
    };


public:

    HashTable(int numItems) {
        if (numItems <= 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid HashTable size");
        }
        currItems = 0;

        //B must be the next prime after 2 * numItems
        B = nextPrime(numItems * 2);

        items = new Bucket[B]; // <-- you forgot the 'new'

        items[0].keyVal; //ERROR: undeclared identifier
    }

    bool insert(T* newItem, int key) {
        bool retVal = false;

        if (currItems < B && newItem != NULL) { //cannot insert to full HashTable
            int index = getOpenBucket(key);

            items[index].dataPtr = newItem; //ERROR:undeclared
            items[index].keyVal = key;      //ERROR:undeclared

            retVal = true;
            currItems++;
        }

        return retVal;
    }

private:


    Bucket * items; //array of buckets
    int B; //size of itemArray
    int currItems; //track number of items in HashTable

};
```

ps. do not do this: `using namespace std;` in header files - ever.

It is evil and antisocial as it poisons the global namespace of every cpp file that includes your header. It's a guaranteed way to ensure that no-one will ever use your library.

Comment: Even after moving the struct declaration to the beginning of the class I am still receiving the `hashtable.h(64): error C2065: 'keyValue': undeclared identifier` error. Could this have anything to do with my declaration of the my HashTable in another class? `HashTable<Customer> * customers = new HashTable<Customer>(10000);`  And thanks for the namespace tip, I'll fix that right away!

Comment: `items = new Bucket[B];` you forgot the `new`